# mysql get lastess articles from table with every category

Tags: mysql

I working on project tintuc at http://www.xaluan.com

i have two table cuted to simple like this

```
table articles
 ID - Title - Des - CatID
table category
 CatID - catTitle
```

normally i will run a loop over category table to received CatID and catTile then run again loop on articles table to have 4 latest articles belong to that CatID

## result on website like this

```
catTitle 1 
 - lastes article belong to catID 1
 - second last artice belong to catID 1
catTitle 2
 - lastess article belong to catID 2
 - second last article belong to catID 2
```

I think the loop over category table then loop many time on article table for each catId is not effect way.

Please help with most effect mysql query to have same result.

thank a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the result in the format you mentioned, however, you can run this query and loop over the result to format the data to look like hwa tyou have shown above.

```
SELECT c.catTitle, c.CatID, a.Title, a.ID , a.Des
FROM category c, artices a
WHERE c.CatID  = a.CatID 
ORDER BY c.CatID ASC, a.ID DESC
```

EDIT:

If you want only top 4, use this query

```
SELECT c.catTitle, c.CatID, a.Title, a.ID , a.Des
FROM category c, (SELECT ID, Title, Des, CatID
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, Title, Des, CatID,
      @num := if(@CatID = `CatID`, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
      @CatID := `CatID` AS dummy
  FROM articles
  ORDER BY CatID, ID DESC
) AS x WHERE x.row_number <= 4) a
WHERE c.CatID  = a.CatID
ORDER BY c.CatID ASC, a.ID DESC
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ab20/8)

Comment: thanks, but this look like not limit number of artices on each catid on result. I just need show 4 article only, so with 3 category will have 12 rows result.

Comment: Thanks.. i have just test your query with our data .. around 600000 rows .. it took very long time, some time it over limit of sql runtime ..

Comment: @BinhNguyen You need to have index on columns to fasten things up. like `CatID` column. Usually any column that you use often in `WHERE` or `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If `ID` is what you're sorting by (I don't see an article date to order by), the query can be written as;

```
SELECT a.* FROM articles a
WHERE (
   SELECT COUNT(b.id) FROM articles b WHERE a.id < b.id AND a.CatID = b.CatID
) < 4;
```

It shows all articles where there exist less than 4 newer articles in the same category.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f6bb9/3).

Comment: thanks for the query very short but it took very long time too.. on our data with 600k rows data..

Comment: @BinhNguyen Do you have any indexes on the table? (specifically on `article.CatID` and `article.id`)?

Comment: Yes those all have index colume for articleid and catid .. .. Curently I have to go back old way.. list all the categories then loop over one by one to get lastest 4 artiles from each ..